# Nesting loops and statements in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, loops, nested

I have this code and I want to add checkbox according to  fetched number from database with PHP and when clicked on checkbox update a field in db with JQuery, this work for 1 checkbox but this cant work for more checkbox and Also my PHP loop does not work how i can add checkbox with loops and when user click on any checkbox update His own field on database, anybody can resolve my problem ?

My JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mycheckbox').change(function () {
        var returnVal = ("Are " + "you sure?");
        if (returnVal) {
            postToServer($(this).prop("checked"));

        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));
        }
    });
    function postToServer(state) {
        let value = (state) ? 1 : 0;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkbox.php',
            data: {'value': +value},
            success: function (response) {
                //handle response
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my PHP code:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `users` ";
$result1= mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
$row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$lights=$row1["lights"];
for ($i=0; $i < $lights; $i++){
    if ($row["value"]=='1'){
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"checkbox\" id=\"mycheckbox\" checked=\"checked\">";
    } else {
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"checkbox\" id=\"mycheckbox\" >";
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown all of your jQuery code. Also, all of your checkboxes have the same ID, which is not allowed in HTML. Maybe something like `id=\"mycheckbox{$i}\"` would be better?

Comment: I did it but did not answer This is my first jQuery code:$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mycheckbox').change(function () { @GregSchmidt

Comment: what is the name of the column in the database that determines if the checkbox should be checked

Comment: the name of field is 'value' @FestusYuma

Comment: i'll edit my answer, hope it helps @mehdiMollazehi

Comment: this code run 1 more checkbox for any user or 1 checkbox?  What does it do $row['id'] in this loop?@FestusYuma

Comment: As I said, your checkboxes need unique IDs, that's how HTML works. To make this work, you'll need to change the selector on your change function, maybe `'.checkbox'` instead of `'#mycheckbox'`, create some way (with a data attribute, for example) to get the `id` from `$(this)` in that function, pass it to your `postToServer` function and have it post it to the server with the value, and then use that ID in your `checkbox.php`.

Comment: @mehdiMollazehi it creates a checkbox for each user, the $row["id"] is there in order to make each checkbox have a unique id, id represents the primary key of the users table (i.e rename it to the name of your primary key if it isn't named id)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue with your loop not running and should print out the checkbox for each user

```
$users= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users)) {
    if ($row["value"]=='1'){
       echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="mycheckbox-'.$row["id"].'" checked="checked">';
    }else {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="mycheckbox-'.$row["id"].'" >';
    }
}
```

Added the id of the user to each checkbox id in order to make each one have a unique id

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.checkbox').change(function () { 
        var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if (returnVal == true) {
            postToServer($(this).val());

        } else {
            $(this).prop("checked", !$(this).is(":checked"));
        }
    });
    function postToServer(state) {
        let value = state;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'checkbox.php',
            data: {'value': value},
            success: function (response) {
                //handle response
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**PHP Code :**

```html
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);    
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
?>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row["id"] ?>">
<?php 
    }
?>
```